# RealmSwift initializer: self used before super.init call

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
import RealmSwift
import Realm

public class Card : Object {
    var username : String
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String


    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]?) {
        guard let dictionary = dictionary , let username = dictionary["username"] as? String else { return else}

        self.username = username
        self.firstName = firstName 
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    required public init() {
        fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }

    required public init( realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required public init( value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
       fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I get:

> 'self' used before super.init call

I had my class working properly. After adding RealmSwift i'm getting those errors. If I add `super.init()` it complains:

> Property 'self.username' not initialized at super.init call

Comment: Please be aware that `String` properties managed by Realm must be declared with `dynamic var` or you'll not get the results you expect. See [Realm's property declaration cheatsheet](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cheatsheet) for more info.

Comment: Thank you bdash will modify them to dynamic var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here.

First and foremost, when [adding custom initializers to subclasses of `Object`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#adding-custom-initializers-to-object-subclasses), they must be declared as convenience initializers. It's not possible to correctly implement `Object`'s required initializer from a subclass, and using a convenience initializer removes the need to try and do this. It also means you'll instead delegate to `self.init()` rather than `super.init()` from within your custom initializer.

Secondly, stored properties must have an initial value. Without the initial value the Swift compiler will not synthesize initializers for your class (in this case, a version of `init()` that calls through to the base class).

Finally, as I mentioned elsewhere, properties of type `String` must be declared using Swift's `dynamic` modifier to allow Realm to intercept get / set operations on them.

By following these guidelines you'll end up with something like so:

```
public class Card : Object {
    dynamic var username: String = ""
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName: String = ""

    convenience init?(dictionary: [String:Any]?) {
        guard let dictionary = dictionary,
            let username = dictionary["username"] as? String,
            let firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String,
            let lastName = dictionary["lastName"] as? String
            else { return nil }

        self.init()

        self.username = username
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, was wondering how would I go about having an init() now that my initial init()  is convenience init?  Thank you once again!  The error shows up as fatal error: init() has not been implemented

Comment: If you're hitting a new problem, I'd suggest asking a new question and providing the code that is triggering the error. It's hard to speculate as to what's going on without more information.

Comment: I added a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728234/realmswift-required-public-init-error

Answer (score 3):

Because your properties are String.

From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)...

**Setting Initial Values for Stored Properties**

*Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.
You can set an initial value for a stored property within an initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the property’s definition. These actions are described in the following sections.*

You have two options:

1)

```
var username : String = ""
var firstName : String = ""
var lastName : String = ""
```

2)

```
var username : String?
var firstName : String?
var lastName : String?
```

Comment: Thank you @facumenzella but initially without adding :Object to my class it wouldn't complain about strings, is it because of :Object?

Comment: That's because you did not inherit from another class. Now that you do, by default you inherit all the initializers but, by adding at least one, you don't. That's why you must call super, because you are adding a custom initializer to a subclass of Object. Personally I opted for another approach with Realm objects. I make all the properties mutable, and then I add a custom setter. I haven't found a better solution yet.