# RealmSwift : required public init() error

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
import RealmSwift
import Realm

public class Card : Object {
    dynamic var username: String = ""
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName: String = ""

    convenience init?(dictionary: [String:Any]?) {
        guard let dictionary = dictionary , let username =  dictionary["username"] as? String else { return else}
        self.init()
        self.username = username
        self.firstName = firstName 
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    required public init() {
        fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }

    required public init( realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required public init( value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
       fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

As per suggestions I made the variables dynamic var as opposed to var and initialized them to empty strings.  Initially I had the convenience init() as just init(). After adding realm the convenience init() calls self.init() as per suggestions. Now the default implementation asks throws

```
(fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
```

What should be inside the required public init()? Do I have to initialize the variables again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710774/1991710), by switching your `init?` method to a convenience initializer, it's no longer necessary to override the various required initializers from the superclass. You can simply remove the three `required public init` methods from your subclass.

```
public class Card : Object {
    dynamic var username: String = ""
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName: String = ""

    convenience init?(dictionary: [String:Any]?) {
        guard let dictionary = dictionary,
            let username = dictionary["username"] as? String,
            let firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String,
            let lastName = dictionary["lastName"] as? String
            else { return nil }

        self.init()

        self.username = username
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Comment: `Software Engineer at Realm` wow wow wow) Stackoverflow is a nice place to ask questions)

Comment: Right! I feel stupid now - For some reason always thought those three required public init had to be there regardless even though you had mentioned it in the code as well previously!

Comment: No problem! In general, if you ever find yourself having to `import Realm` while using Realm Swift, its an indication that something isn't right. Realm Swift's API can be used entirely without referring to symbols from the Objective-C framework (though it must be included within your app as RealmSwift itself uses the Objective-C framework).

Comment: Correct !  I took it off and looks good now. Will play some more with Realm in storing and retrieving, thank you and the team for the great work!