# Can you add a designated initializer to a Realm Object subclass?

Tags: swift, realm

Consider the following:

```
protocol P {
    init(data: Data) throws
}

enum PError: Error {
    case invalidData
}

final class O: Object, P {
    @Persisted var name: String

    init(data: Data) throws {
        guard let name = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw PError.invalidData
        }
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }
}
```

`O` inherits from Realm `Object` and conforms to `P`. To satisfy the requirements of `P`, `O` implements a designated initializer.

https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/4889#issuecomment-296301901 quotes some docs that no longer exist (or have moved) which stated:

> When creating your model Object subclasses, you may sometimes want to add your own custom initialization methods for added convenience.
>
> Due to some present limitations with Swift introspection, these methods cannot be designated initializers for the class. Instead, they need to be marked as convenience initializers

Did this change at some point, possibly as a result of https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/pull/6294?

While it's possible to satisfy `P`'s requirement with a convenience initializer, I'm interested to learn whether it's strictly necessary or whether a designated initializer is okay as well.

Comment: Are you asking about a `convenience init`? If so, yes, use it. If not, can you describe what the use case is for your initializer?

Comment: @Jay updated! Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: OK, question is more clear. I believe best practice when initializing Realm objects the is to use a `convenience init` with the first line within the init calling `self.init()`. See [this example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/#define-your-object-model). It's not really possible to correctly implement Object's required initializer from a subclass and using a convenience initializer removes the need to try and do that. You could also add a function to perform the init `func configure(param1:param2:...) {` which would flow through to subclasses if needed.

Comment: Are there any docs on this?

Comment: I wish. Most of the documentation that existed on the old Realm site got blown out by the new site. You can find a smattering of references info like [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/1101) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710340/realmswift-initializer-self-used-before-super-init-call/44710774#44710774) but the bottom line is that a Realm object is already a subclass and has a designated init. Is there a reason you cannot use a convenience init? The protocol conforming is still available and/or subclassing P.